# Выводить данные с input списком

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, form

Такой вопрос.
Как при помощи ajax сделать так, чтобы после отправки данных, введенных в `input`, и нажатия на `button`, эти данные выводились **списком**. Т.е. при введение новых значений с `input` на экране оставались старые значения, а ниже вводилось новое значение. (если возможно с PHP и без БД). Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: И ajax-то тут зачем? Берете текст инпута и вставляете в нужное место на странице, сервер зачем грузить?

Answer (score 0):

Так, примерно (jQuery way):

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function () {

  $textInput = $('#id'),
  $block = $('#wrapper');
  
  if (!$textInput.val()) {
    alert('empty input');
    return false;
  }
  
  // ajax goes here
  // and then in ajax success
  $block.append('<li>' + $textInput.val() + '</li>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="name" id="id" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="send" />

<ul id="wrapper"></ul>
```